# Remove elements at a set of indices in a multidimensional array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a multidimensional array `A` with 1000 elements (1000x3). I have another vector with index positions of elements I want to remove from this array.

I've tried using this `A(indices) = []` or `A(indices,:,:) = []`, but the problem is that the result changes `A`'s dimension, so if `indices` has 10 elements, I find `A`'s size become `2990x1` instead of `990x3`. Anyone can advise how to remove the elements having the `indices` in `A` where `A`'s dimensions won't change will still be `n x 3`?

Comment: Thanks! it worked :) you can post your answer so that I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to filter the matrix, for example,

```
A=rand(1000,3);
A(A(:,1)>0.9)=[];
```

which removes the rows of `A` that have a value greater than `0.9` in the first column.

I'm not sure why your original approach didn't work though.